# Using Files From Multiple Projects in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm trying to use a class I already defined in one project to supplement a class in another project. I added the folder that holds Project A in to the search directories for the compiler and the linker in Project B, added the file for ClassA.h to Project B, and included ClassA.h in ClassB.h. I get errors about an undefined reference to various functions in Class A. How do I get Class A to work in Project B?

Comment: You're not compiling the .cpp file is my guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to compile the .cpp file as suggested by Pubby.